# Pocohud and Hoxhud Compatibility

Tags: payday-2

I currently have HoxHud, and find it very useful, but I recently I have seen some players reporting useful messages in the chat such as health replenishment and warnings of 3 downs. I would like to get Pocohud for that feature of reporting things into the chat but prefer the HoxHud GUI and features such as not having to hold down F to interact with pagers or lock picking. I was wondering if their was a way to install both mods, but keep the HoxHud GUI and core features, and also have the Pocohud chat feature. Also I should mention that I do not currently have Pocohud installed, only HoxHud.

Comment: I've heard of people that run both, but I think it requires a bit of hacking in order to enable both at the same time, since they both write the same file for loading their individual scripts.

Comment: Could you link me to a guide on how to do the 'little bit of hacking' please?

Comment: Please avoid using HoxHud, it crashes often and the anticheat deletes your bags every time a new heist is released.

Comment: This post is old, I only use PocoHud now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They should work fine installed alongside each other. PocoHud won't disable HoxHud's features. Since you already have HoxHud, just download [PocoHud](https://steamcommunity.com/groups/pocomods), and follow the instructions in installation.txt to install it. From installation.txt: "You should see a folder named 'poco' inside the 'PAYDAY 2' game folder. If you intend to use HoxHud simultaneously, always keep HH's DLLs."

To configure PocoHud, press backspace in-game. Go to PocoHud Options » Chat to configure PocoHud's chat options. The rest of PocoHud's features can be disabled in its options.